# How to give Android notch support to React Native App

Tags: android, react-native

I want to make my app's window draw on both side of the notch. I have followed a guide from [this](https://proandroiddev.com/making-notch-friendly-apps-for-android-75776272be5c) article and created **values-v28** folder inside my **res** folder. After that I have created styles.xml inside the values-v28 folder and added the following code

```
<style name="ActivityTheme">
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
        shortEdges
    </item>
</style>
```

But still my app’s window always gets drawn below the notch. I am totally confused what's the correct way to do this.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I have the same result. Using react-native 0.59.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working!

I wrote this [article](https://twitter.com/brunolemos/status/1167963091167895552?s=20) explaining the steps.

Here's a TL/DR:

1. Add these lines to your `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
+        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
+            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
+            layoutParams.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
+            getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
+            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
+            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
+        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

2. And then install and link [react-native-safe-area-context](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context) to handle the notch paddings. Here's the final result:

[image]

Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StatusBar, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { useSafeArea } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'

export function App() {
  const safeAreaInsets = useSafeArea()

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#ffca28',
        paddingTop: safeAreaInsets.top,
        paddingBottom: safeAreaInsets.bottom,
        paddingLeft: safeAreaInsets.left,
        paddingRight: safeAreaInsets.right,
      }}
    >
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#7cb342" />

      <Text style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: 'center' }}>Top</Text>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: 'center' }}>Left</Text>
        <Text style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: 'center' }}>Right</Text>
      </View>
      <Text style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: 'center' }}>Bottom</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I actually did the same thing. But I am going accept your answer.